# Rename an Amazon RDS Option group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm creating a script that deletes an AWS RDS DB instance (Postgres), its parameter group, subnet group, and option group. **It works like a charm except for the deletion of the option group because of the final snapshots**.

When deleting RDS instance, if a user chooses param `--no-skip-final-snapshot`, a final snapshot is automatically linked to the option group. I need to keep those snapshots (and so the option groups), that's why I would need to rename the OG, from `og-xxx-group` to `og-xxx-group-22-05-2019`, for example.

Is there a way, using awscli to rename an option group or dissociate an option group of a final snapshot or whatever?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not seem possible to rename an option group.

An Option Group is used to specify features for an RDS database, so it seems that the Snapshot is linked to the Option Group so that it can be restored to a compatible configuration.

There are API calls to create, delete and modify option groups. However, the `modify_option_group()` call does not include the ability to modify the name of the Option Group.

So, it looks like you'll need to keep them around.